# Strange numpy.array behaviour - wrong conversion of nested list of lists or I do not understand how it works?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I wrote some program to test if numpy.array nested lists conversion works and I found that it works as simple as it should be.

I tried to do the same on a real life example (machine learning arrays) and it stopped working. I cannot present the whole data since it is too large.

Let us assume that I have x nested list:

x is list of list of list of float:

```
type(x), type(x[0]), type(x[0][0]), type(x[0][0][0])
```

is:

```
(<class 'list'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'float'>)
```

all elements are correctly typed:

```
type(x)
<class 'list'>
set(type(a) for a in x)
{<class 'list'>}
set(type(b) for a in x for b in a)
{<class 'list'>}
set(type(c) for a in x for b in a for c in b)
{<class 'float'>}
```

I do:

```
xa = numpy.array(x)
type(xa), type(xa[0]), type(xa[0][0]), type(xa[0][0][0])
```

**and this conversion gives a strange result**:

```
(<class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'float'>)
```

**Why it is off? Why are some nested lists not converted?**

```
(<class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>)
```

Why does numpy.array conversion fail or not complete - can you give some hints?

I tested this code and it works for a hand-created y variable:

```
y = [[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]], [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]]
type(y), type(y[0]), type(y[0][0]), type(y[0][0][0])
(<class 'list'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'float'>)
ya = numpy.array(y)
type(ya), type(ya[0]), type(ya[0][0]), type(ya[0][0][0])
(<class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>)
```

y is exactly the same as x, but for x, conversion does not work. What can be the problem?

How to convert x or fix it to allow conversion like y, as both are the same nested lists?

Comment: Probably your lists in the "real life example" do not all have consistent sizes. For example, if you do `np.array([[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0]]])` you will see something similar.

Comment: @jdehesa I try to check you hint now :) - maybe see I checked types and all types is consistent. Looks it can be the best hint or answer.

Comment: @jdehesa Looks that is answer I just miscalculated index and some list are not symmetric but smaller the previous. That was root cause. Thank you for saving a lot of life :)

Comment: Look at `ya.shape` and `ya.dtype`.  If something like (2,2,3) and `float` it's a multidimensional array.  If (2,) and `object` is 1d array of lists, because the lists vary is size.